# Setup Microsoft Azure SAML 2.0 SSO on an IIS website

Tags: azure, iis

I have built a web-based application hosted on IIS, but my client wants it to use Azure for SSO. I've read through some documentation, but I am rather lost. I haven't found any documentation that gives me a clear set of instructions on how to integrate SSO on an IIS website which has no current connection with Azure or anything else like that. Do I need to purchase a license from Microsoft to do this? I have some of the details, such as the XML certificate file for my client. But I really don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a configuration guide for non-gallery applications :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications

To enable your application for SAML SSO at IIS level, you can use Shibboleth ISAPI Filter https://www.shibboleth.net/products/service-provider/

Or integrate SAML2 in your OWIN application with Sustainsys.Saml2 library : https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2

You can also find a step-by-step instructions on Azure Portal :

[image]

Comment: The first URL is a set of instructions my client would use to connect their Azure to my application, once I have SAML2/SSO setup, and assuming my application is not listed in Microsoft's gallery of pre-approved applications, correct? I don't see much in there that helps me configure my application. So it sounds like IIS won't do this on its own, I need to install Shibboleth or Sustainsys.Saml2? Likewise, I have the step-by-step instructions in your screenshot, but those are instructions my client would use, again not really helpful for my configuration/install issue?

Comment: @BBDesign Your are correct, your client need to preregistre your application in Azure AD give you certificate and SAMLv2 endpoints. After, your application or Web-server need support SAMLv2. To manage SAMLv2 at IIS level you need to install Shibboleth otherwise you need integrate SAMLv2 support to your application (so you need to find a good library for it). The instructions on the screenshot is for you.